# About library <libutil.h> in utility 'df', Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, include

In university i have task - to find source code of linux utility 'df', and write some
analogy of it, based on source code of it. 
I try to use this code - 
https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-212.1/df/df.c
but i can't find include file 'libutil.h' on my linux. And so on, i can't try to use this source code.
I don't think that simple download libutil.h will help. What can you say about this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux system? Then you can figure out which installation package the `df` program comes from, and from there you can find the source. If you don't have Linux, why not? Just install it in a virtual machine.

Comment: I think the idea is for you to write you own code, not to compile source code you can find on the internet...

Comment: The reason why you can't compile with the code you have downloaded is because it comes from the OSX system (You're on a linux system). I'd follow the answer given by @starrify. Or download it directly from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/df.c;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just updating df today :)
Your df command on Linux does come from the GNU coreutils.
The handiest way to browse that with clickable references is:

http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c

BTW the general procedure for finding code for any Linux program
is useful to know. I've documented the basic flow for rpm based distros here:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/oss_bug_flow.html

Answer (score 2):

`df` is part of [`GNU Coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), so you could fetch its source code and look for `df` inside it.

Comment: yes, my second think about 'how to solve' this task - is about using this package. if i can't solve problem which i post here, a will use codes from this

Comment: @alena_fox_spb Well I'm actually trying to help on your first need "to find source code of linux utility 'df'". Actually the `df.c` you found comes from OSX which is an Unix not Linux.